# Автоматическое монтирование раздела жесткого диска

Tags: windows, c++, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Стоит Ubuntu 13.04+Windows 8. Есть раздел жесткого диска W: и он играет роль хранилища для Apache.В Ubuntu он монтируется в /var/www, а в Windows просто W: и все настроено на него. Я себе так сделал, чтоб можно было под разными осями кодить без переносов файлов, да и просто очень удобно - типа рабочий диск.Проблема в том, что Ubuntu при монтировании удаляет букву и под виндой приходится постоянно вручную назначать. Причем Ubuntu затирает букву, даже когда я в нее не захожу - наверно еще на этапе grub.Кто-нибудь знает как кодом (С/С++/С#, Java, DOS .bat и т.д.) написать скрипт/программу под винду, чтоб можно было добавить в автозапуск и он при входе автоматически монтировался.
Или может есть иные варианты решения?

UPDATE:
Попробовал зайти в стандартный диск менеджер винды: https://www.dropbox.com/s/snu76c1z5o70113/w.png Думаю косяк в том, что нужный диск W через 2 раздела от E, на которых стоит Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Дело не в этом.
1) В Linux-системах диски букв не имеют и автомонтируются по своему id.
2) В Windows диски монтируются тоже по id но с автоматическим присвоением буквы диска (и очень часто это закрепление слетает, как и многое в винде), кроме дисков A:\ и B:\ - это наследие DOS  и их имена жестко закреплены.
Замените W на A или B - и он всегда у вас будет монтироваться под этой буквой.

Comment: @Justicet, А в чем причина "слета" закрепления буквы в винде?  П.С. Смена буквы повлечет перенастройку серверов под обеими ОС и всех виртуальных хостов + потеря таких мелочей, как отображение последних проектов в IDE.  Вариант трудозатратный.

Comment: Смена буквы обычно бывает при подключении внешних девайсов. Но я ни разу не видел случая, чтобы к компу было подключено более 20-ти девайсов с внешней памятью!

Comment: Justicet, а вот как раз на A и B - нельзя! Эти буковки традиционно застолблены для флоппи-дисководов!

Comment: Флешки великолепно "садятся" на А и В. И если флешку подключить к другому компу, а потом снова к рабочему - буква диска обязательно меняется. Замечено и в ХРюше и в 7-ке. Причины - не знаю.  Любому линуху абсолютно пофиг какие буквы назначены виндой для данного диска. У него принцип подключения другой. У меня есть машина и с Линухом и с Виндой - но таких танцев с дисками ни разу не замечено (RFR17.1)  Может есть смысл перейти на виртуализацию?

Answer (score 0):

Что конкретно можно сделать:

1. Зайти в Панель управления->Администрирование->Управление компьютером->Запоминающие устройства->Управление дисками.
2. Забить там нужную буковку для своего диска.
3. Всё! Жёстко забил буковку, и так оно и будет, независимо ни от чего (правда, только в вендах)!
4. В Лине, как и в прочих никсах - совершенно другой подход. В /etc/fstab надо прописать вендовый раздел с соответствующими опциями. В том числе там можно указать и автомонтирование. А уж куда монтировать - это твой выбор!

Comment: @Anton Reshin, ну я назначаю через Acronis. Попробую через Disk Manager  Попробовал: https://www.dropbox.com/s/snu76c1z5o70113/w.pngДумаю косяк в том, что нужный диск W через 2 раздела от E, на которых стоит Ubuntu

Comment: А можно монтирование этого диска в /etc/fstab в студию? Хотелось бы глянуть для начала на него, батник в автозапуск на вин это дело 5-ти минут, но Вам действительно нужны такие костыли? Давайте разберёмся, мне интересно.